# Почему переменные равны , хотя это не так, в php?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте уважаемые знатоки.
Почему выполнив этот код мы получим "равны"?
Это же абсурд.

```
echo ('9 9 1' == 9) ? 'равны' : 'не равны'; // равны
```

Как '9 9 1' может быть равен девятке или наоборот?
Только пожалуйста не отправляйте меня читать документацию о том как сравниваются типы в php. Она все равно не отвечает на вопрос как такое возможно.

P.S. php v 7.2

Comment: Потому что слабая типизация и строка преобразуется в число

Comment: вообще-то у PHP левостороннее приведение типов. А как у вас так получается? $ php -r 'echo ("9 9 1" == 9) ? "равны" : "не равны";'  выдает "не равны" (PHP 8,1)

Comment: @Дмитрий в 7.4 выдаёт «равны»

Comment: Дествительно, до 8-й версии выдает "равны", восьмая версия выдает "не равны". [проверить](https://onlinephp.io/?s=s7EvyCjg5UpNzshX0FC3VLBUMFRXsLVVsNRUsFdQv9hwYcOFTRf2XuxWV7BSUL-w98JWBSQxawA%2C&v=8.0.27%2C7.4.33%2C5.2.17)

Comment: вау... Это так. На 7.2 посмотрел. В таком случае явно попытка приведения строки к целому, по аналогии с (int)"9 9 1" даст 9. Так что если хотим четкого сравнения нужно === (но все же немного в шоке)))

Comment: Да я сам немного в шоке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не абсурд, а PHP

В данном случае строка приводится к числу. А так как числа **9 9 1** не существует, то берется подстрока до первого пробела и она приводится к числу.
В данном случае это будет 9

Проверить это можно просто

```php
echo(intval("9 9 1"));
```

Выдаст **9**

а

```php
echo(intval("99 1"));
```

выдаст **99**

Т.е. в вашем случае идет сравнение **9** и **9** - а они равны

Хотите избежать таких ошибок используйте сравнение с учетом типов. Т.е. **===**

```php
echo ('9 9 1' === 9) ? 'равны' : 'не равны'; // не равны
```

Comment: ^ ну вообще я верил до сих пор в левосторонее приведение типов при нетождественном сравнении ))) А вот нет (для 7.х в 8.1 иначе)